# Use a Ternary Expression for Conditional Rendering in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

For the challenge https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/front-end-libraries/react/use-a-ternary-expression-for-conditional-rendering
When I am entering the code:

```
const inputStyle = {
  width: 235,
  margin: 5
};

class CheckUserAge extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Change code below this line
this.state = {
      input: '',
      userAge: ''
    };
    // Change code above this line
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      input: e.target.value,
      userAge: ''
    });
  }
  submit() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      userAge: state.input
    }));
  }
  render() {
    const buttonOne = <button onClick={this.submit}>Submit</button>;
    const buttonTwo = <button>You May Enter</button>;
    const buttonThree = <button>You Shall Not Pass</button>;
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Enter Your Age to Continue</h3>
        <input
          style={inputStyle}
          type='number'
          value={this.state.input}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <br />
        {/* Change code below this line */}
{this.state.input==''?buttonOne:(this.state.input<18?buttonTwo:buttonThree)}
        {/* Change code above this line */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It replaces the button as soon as I enter the value in the input box
but if I replace the code with:

```
{this.state.userAge >= 18
          ? buttonTwo
          : this.state.userAge === ""
          ? buttonOne
          : buttonThree}
```

It dosn't do it unless I submit the input.
Can anyone explain what basically is the difference?

Comment: Looks like you inverted the order of the first two "conditions" and also removed the parens for grouping. Since you changed the structure it's likely the result could be different.

Comment: Because `'' > 18` is false until you submit and the `input` state is saved to the `userAge` state.

Comment: ya thanks, I got it